# How to generate the first twenty powers of x?

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

So, I've got X, a 300-by-1 vector and I'd like [1, X, X*X, X*X*X, ... , X*X*...*X], a 300-by-twenty matrix.

How should I do this?

```
X=[2;1]
[X,X.*X,X.*X.*X]

ans =

   2   4   8
   1   1   1
```

That works, but I can't face typing out the whole thing. Surely I don't have to write a for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to **minimize the number of operations**:

```
cumprod(repmat(X(:),1,20),2) %// replace "20" by the maximum exponent you want
```

---

**Benchmarking**: for `X` of size 300x1, maximum exponent 20. I measure time with `tic`, `toc`, averaging 1000 times. Results (averages):

- Using `cumprod` (this answer): 8.0762e-005 seconds
- Using `bsxfun` (answer by @thewaywewalk): 8.6170e-004 seconds

Comment: I was just typing this same solution - way to go!

Comment: @Shai Thanks! It's always important to re-use previous results :-)

Comment: like for the bsxfun solution, you should mention that `X` needs to be a columnvector,

Answer (score 5):

Use `bsxfun` for a neat solution, or go for Luis Mendo's extravaganza to save some time ;)

```
powers = 1:20;
x = 1:20;

result = bsxfun(@power,x(:),powers(:).');
```

gives:

```
 1    1    1 ...
 8   16   32 ...
27   81  243 ...
64  256 1024 ...
... ...  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The [element-wise power operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) `.^` should do what you need:

```
x .^ (1:20)
```

(assuming `x` is a column vector.)

Comment: @LuisMendo: You mean it doesn't work for row vectors?

Comment: For the example in the OP: `[2;1].^(1:20)`: error, sizes don't match

Comment: @LuisMendo: That works fine for me in Octave (don't have Matlab to hand at the moment).  Perhaps Octave has improved things?

Comment: Oh, that must be the reason. I'm using Matlab (2010b)

Answer (score 0):

Use power. It raises something to the power of y, and repeats if y is a vector.

```
power(x,1:300)
```

edit: power and .^ operator are equivalent.

Comment: Or even `x .^ (1:20)`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. It won't let me accept the answer since you were so quick. I'll try to remember to come back and do it later!